# Azure DevOps pipeline for Pulumi when using Azure blob storage as backend

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pulumi

Instead of using Pulumi service (managed) backend, I am using Azure blob container as stack state backend. According to the documentation, Pulumi CLI would expect `AZURE_STORAGE_KEY` (or `AZURE_STORAGE_SAS_TOKEN`) environment variable in the Pipeline Agent.

When account key is provided as pipeline variable, it's working. **But when account key is stored in KeyVault as secret, it's not working.**

**What I did:**

```
Account key in KayVault as secret
→ (pipeline variable group) Link secrets from an Azure key vault as variables
→ → (Pipeline variables) Link variable group
→ → → Make account key available to Pulumi CLI (in pipeline agent) as environment variable
```

**The problem:**

- KeyVault secret name can not contain '_'
- Secret name for account key is `AZURE-STORAGE-KEY` (not `AZURE_STORAGE_KEY` since secret name can not contain '_')
- Environment variable in pipeline agent becomes `AZURE-STORAGE-KEY`

So, the problem is obvious: **environment variable name mismatch** → Pulumi CLI is not getting what it expects (`AZURE_STORAGE_KEY`).

FYI,

- I am using "classic editor" and "Pulumi Azure Pipelines Task"
- I tried creating a pipeline variable with "Name: `azure.storage.key`, Value: `$(AZURE-STORAGE-KEY)`", hoping that this variable value will be set from KeyVault secret since secrets are linked to variable group → did not working
- Tried to set environment variable in a PowerShell task (`$env:AZURE_STORAGE_KEY = "$(AZURE-STORAGE-KEY)"`) mentioned that this PowerShell task is in front of "Pulumi Azure Pipelines Task" → did not work
- Pulumi documentation [Pulumi Task Extension for Azure Pipelines](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/continuous-delivery/azure-devops/#pulumi-task-extension-for-azure-pipelines) and
  Other StackOverflow question [Pulumi Azure Pipeline task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61226383/4802664) did not help

**How to solve this problem?**
Is there any better approach? (providing account key to Pulumi CLI in pipeline agent securely).
Is there any way to achieve this if YAML (`azure-pipelines.yml`) is used? how? (Any work around or hint would also help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was able to solve the problem :**

- As mentioned in my question, KeyVault secrets are linked to variable group
- Variable group is linked to pipeline variables (so now KeyVault secrets are available as pipeline variables)
- According to Microsoft documentation, secret type variables are not injected into the task automatically
- Used `env` for task to inject environment variables (that are expected by Pulumi CLI) by interpolating pipeline variables

`azure-pipelines.yml`

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
- group: "pulumi-demo-vg"

job: PulumiUpJob
displayName: Pulumi Up Stack Deployment Job
steps:
- task: Pulumi@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'pulumi-demo-sc' # sc -> Service Connection
    command: 'up'
    loginArgs: 'azblob://pulumi-backend-container'
    args: '--yes'
    stack: 'dev'
  env:
    AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT: "xxxsa"
    AZURE_STORAGE_KEY: $(AZURE-STORAGE-KEY)
    AZURE_CLIENT_ID: $(AZURE-CLIENT-ID)
    AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: $(AZURE-CLIENT-SECRET)
    AZURE_TENANT_ID: $(AZURE-TENANT-ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable using a different powershell task:

```
echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=AZURE_STORAGE_KEY;]$(AZURE-STORAGE-KEY)
```

Comment: Did not work -> `##[error]Pulumi CLI login command failed. error: problem logging in: unable to open bucket azblob://pulumi-backend-container: open bucket azblob://pulumi-backend-container: invalid credentials`

Comment: If you print the variable, does it record it correctly with the correct key?

Comment: Created 2 PowerShell Script Tasks : Task 1 doing what you mentioned in your answer, Task 2 `Write-Host "$(AZURE_STORAGE_KEY)"`. Getting error from Task 1 -> `Cannot process command because of one or more missing
     | mandatory parameters: InputObject.
`

Comment: Forgot to mention, using "Target script type: Inline" for both PowerShell tasks, don't know if "Target script type: File Path" would make any difference